# Fatal Error after WP Installations, is it a problem of wp-settings.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I am facing this error every week after I install Wordpress.
I tried uploading a new `wp-settings.php` file from GitHub but that doesn't seem to be working too.

Error:

> Warning: require(/home/cntrlb8k/public_html/wp-includes/post.php):
> failed to open stream: Permission denied in
> /home/cntrlb8k/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 166
>
> Warning: require(/home/cntrlb8k/public_html/wp-includes/post.php):
> failed to open stream: Permission denied in
> /home/cntrlb8k/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 166
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
> '/home/cntrlb8k/public_html/wp-includes/post.php'
> (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php')
> in /home/cntrlb8k/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 166

Comment: Did you try installing the latest zip from wp? I guess some file or other may be missing or corrupted.. or better use wp cli which is quicker

Comment: You have a permissions problem. Look for recommended WordPress file permission settings.

Comment: I tried installing the latest zip from Wordpress.org through ftp, but I encounter the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**If on Unix**

```
chmod 755 -R /home/cntrlb8k/public_html/wp-includes/
```

**If on Windows**

1. In Windows Explorer, right-click the file or folder you want to work with.
2. From the pop-up menu, select Properties, and then in the Properties dialog box click the Security tab.
3. In the Name list box, select the user, contact, computer, or group whose permissions you want to view. If the permissions are dimmed, it means the permissions are inherited from a parent object.
4. Click on the Edit button as you wish to modify the user permissions
5. Another window of the permissions of the selected folder will arrive on the screen. Here, under the Group or user names segment, choose the account for which you want to carry out the changes. Then look for the Permissions segment where you will find a list of permissions along with two boxes, allow and deny. Give or withdraw permissions for each operation by choosing the access or deny checkboxes. Once finished, click Apply and Ok buttons.

[Windows permissions source copied from here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/how-to-give-permission-to-the-folders-on-windows/db6bc6d2-750e-4da0-b616-252926c44ffd)